# Which Mapper code is more memory efficiency?

Tags: java, mapreduce, out-of-memory, mapper

I want to build a Mapreduce which has

**Input**:

> key1\t**3,2**|17412|553|15186,19199|15186,3947|15186,5938|15186,15517
>   key2\t925|10295|65182555,7344|7344,925|10295,7344|**3,2**                            key3\t8747|18466|13289|**3,2**|13289,5106|12222,5106|5106,6374
>
> ........

**Output**:min \t (2,3) which is the intersection between every element of value1, every element of value2, ....and valueN.

So, I design my mappers so that

mapper1 will contains intersections between values of key1, key2, key3,

mapper2 will contains intersections between values of key4, key5, key6...

.......

Then my Reducers again take results from these mappers to find final intersections. So, basically my mapper and reducer use the same code. In my code, I find intersection sequentially, i.e., first find intersection between value1 and value2, then the result will be used to intersect with value3, and so on.

My Mapper.

**Mapper-Code1:**

```
public static class MapAPP extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{     
    public static int j=0,k=0;
    public static List<String> min_pre = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> min_current = new ArrayList<>();
    public static Set<String> min_p1 = new HashSet<>();
    public static Set<String> min_c1 = new HashSet<>();
    public static List<String> min_result = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public static Boolean no_exist_min=false;

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String[] v=value.toString().split("\t");
        // aggregate min
        if (no_exist_min==false){
            if (j==0){
                    min_pre= Arrays.asList(v[1].toString().trim().split("\\|"));
                    j=1;
                 }else{
                    min_current= Arrays.asList(v[1].toString().trim().split("\\|")); 
                    for (String p: min_pre){                   
                       min_p1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(p.split(",")));
                       for (String c: min_current){
                           min_c1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(c.split(",")));
                           min_c1.retainAll(min_p1);
                           if (!min_c1.isEmpty()){
                               Joiner m_comma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls();
                               String buff = m_comma.join(min_c1);
                               if (!min_result.contains(buff))
                                    min_result.add(buff);
                           }                       
                       }                   
                    }
                    if (min_result.isEmpty()){
                        no_exist_min=true;          
                    } else {                    
                        min_pre=new ArrayList(min_result);
                        min_result.clear();                       
                    }
            }                   
        }            
    }

    protected void cleanup(Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Joiner m_pipe = Joiner.on("|").skipNulls();
        if (no_exist_min==true){
            con.write(new Text("min"), new Text("no_exist"));
        }else {               
            String min_str = m_pipe.join(min_pre);
            con.write(new Text("min"), new Text(min_str)); 
        }            
    }
}
```

**My Reducer** (is almost same as Mapper):

```
public static class ReduceAPP extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        List<String> pre = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> current = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> p1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> c1 = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Joiner comma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls(); 
        Joiner pipe = Joiner.on("|").skipNulls(); 
        Boolean no_exist=false;
        int i=0;
        // aggregate
        for(Text value: values){
             if (value.toString().trim()=="no_exist"){
                 no_exist=true;
                 break;
                }
             if (i==0){
                    pre= Arrays.asList(value.toString().trim().split("\\|"));
                    i=1;
             }else{
                    current= Arrays.asList(value.toString().trim().split("\\|")); 
                    for (String p: pre){                   
                       p1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(p.split(",")));
                       for (String c: current){
                           c1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(c.split(",")));
                           c1.retainAll(p1);
                           if (!c1.isEmpty()){
                               String buff = comma.join(c1);
                               if (!result.contains(buff))
                                    result.add(buff);
                           }                       
                       }                   
                    }
                    if (result.isEmpty()){
                        no_exist=true;
                        break;
                    }
                    pre=new ArrayList(result);
                    result.clear();                       
             }                   

        }
        if (no_exist==true){
            con.write(key, new Text("no_exist"));
        }
        else{
            String preStr = pipe.join(pre);
            con.write(key, new Text(preStr)); 
        }            
    }
    public static <T> Set<T> union(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
        Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>(setA);
        tmp.addAll(setB);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

I run perfectly on small input files but always out of memory in large files (~450Mb text file). So, I doubt that my java code is not memory efficiency. In my Reducers, I used all local variables and these variables will be destroyed when these Reducer functions finish, so I do not worry about Reducers. But in my Mapper, I have to use static variables. In my Mapper-code1, I used all static variables whereas in my Mapper-code2, I tried to use as least static variables as possible.

I have two questions?

**1) In my Mapper-code1, every static variable is shared between mappers or it is exclusively for 1 mapper?** For example, Suppose I have 5 mappers, Will there be 1 min_pre list created and shared between 5 mappers or will there be 5 min_pre lists for 5 mappers?
What I want is the latter. How to design my mapper so that if I have 5 mappers, there will be 5 min_pre lists?

**2) Mapper-code1 and Mapper-code2, which consumes less memory?**

**Mapper-Code2:**

```
public static class MapAPP extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{     
    public static int j=0,k=0;
    public static List<String> min_pre = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> min_result = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public static Boolean no_exist_min=false;

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String[] v=value.toString().split("\t");
        // aggregate min
        if (no_exist_min==false){
            if (j==0){
                    min_pre= Arrays.asList(v[1].toString().trim().split("\\|"));
                    j=1;
                 }else{
                    List<String> min_current= Arrays.asList(v[1].toString().trim().split("\\|")); 
                    for (String p: min_pre){                   
                       Set<String> min_p1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(p.split(",")));
                       for (String c: min_current){
                           Set<String> min_c1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(c.split(",")));
                           min_c1.retainAll(min_p1);
                           if (!min_c1.isEmpty()){
                               Joiner m_comma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls();
                               String buff = m_comma.join(min_c1);
                               if (!min_result.contains(buff))
                                    min_result.add(buff);
                           }                       
                       }                   
                    }
                    if (min_result.isEmpty()){
                        no_exist_min=true;          
                    } else {                    
                        min_pre=new ArrayList(min_result);
                        min_result.clear();                       
                    }
            }                   
        }            
    }

    protected void cleanup(Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Joiner m_pipe = Joiner.on("|").skipNulls();
        if (no_exist_min==true){
            con.write(new Text("min"), new Text("no_exist"));
        }else {               
            String min_str = m_pipe.join(min_pre);
            con.write(new Text("min"), new Text(min_str)); 
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this'll work correctly at scale. Your mappers aren't sharing their results with each other. Also, 500Mb files can be tested outside of Hadoop

Comment: Thank for reading. I edited my question to make it clearer. Please give me some comments.